# Differences between e.g., viz. and i.e

Tags: differences, abbreviations

What are the differences between "viz." and "e.g." and in which situations each is used? Please also compare the usage with "i.e." if appropriate.

**Edit**: In response to a comment below: I'm asking this as I was framing a sentence

1. "Mobile device manufacturers e.g. Nokia, Samsung, ..."
2. "Mobile device manufacturers viz. Nokia, Samsung, ..."

Which of the above is better usage?

Comment: Also see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*i.e.*: 'In essence' or 'in other words'.  It is used to clarify the original phrase with something specific.   **Edit:** The Latin translation of i.e. is "that is to say" but the words I listed are what helps me remember.

> It was sad to have reached the end, i.e., the final episode in the series.
>
> 'The end' and 'the final episode' are the same thing.

*e.g.*: 'For example'.  Clarify the original phrase with an example.

> He likes fruits, e.g., apples and oranges.
>
> 'apples and oranges' are examples of fruits he likes.  There may be others.

*viz.:* 'Namely' or 'as follows'.   Similar to e.g., it lists examples, but it is normally used when there is a definitive, complete list.  **Edit:** As @Daniel Roseman says in the comment below, this is rarely used today.

> He likes some fruits, viz., apples and oranges.
>
> 'apples and oranges' are the *only* fruits he likes.

So in your specific example of mobile device manufacturers, #1 is probably most likely but it would depend on the sentence:

> AT&T offers phones from several mobile device manufacturers e.g. Nokia and Samsung.  *AT&T offers other phones, too.*
>
> Bob's Phone Shack sells mobile phones from Bob's favorite mobile device manufacturers, viz. Nokia and Samsung.  *Bob only sells Nokia and Samsung phones.*

Sources:

[Grammar Girl - I.e. vs E.g.](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/ie-eg-oh-my.aspx)

[The Oatmeal - I.e. vs E.g.](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie) (very funny)

[Wikipedia - Viz.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videlicet)

Comment: *i.e.* would be better explained as "that is to say", which is closer to the Latin meaning (*id est*)

Comment: Should probably add that although `ie` and `eg` are common, `viz` is almost unknown these days.

Comment: Note that "i.e." stands for the Latin "id est", not "in essence". Besides that technical point, I believe Lynn is correct. Let me add that many people confuse "i.e." and "e.g." and use them interchangeably. For some reason this really annoys me.

Comment: @Jay and Lonesomeday:  You are correct about the literal Latin translation; in my mind it makes the most sense as "in essence" but maybe that's just me :)

Comment: i.e. does actually stand for "id est" (Latin), and not "in essence"

Comment: @Lynn, In your answer, you haven't stated what exactly is the difference between i.e. and viz. What's the difference between "he likes some fruits, viz, apples and oranges" and "he likes some fruits, i.e., apples and oranges"?

Comment: @Pacerier - I.e. in that example doesn't quite fit.  More generally, it comes down to whether you are restating the original point or merely listing examples.  "He likes only orange citrus fruit, i.e. oranges" (restating/clarifying since oranges and orange citrus fruit being more or less equivalent), or "He likes fruit, e.g. apples and oranges" (apples and oranges being just two of many examples of fruit), or "He likes only certain kinds of fruit, viz. apples and strawberries."  (viz implies those are the only ones he likes).

Comment: @Lynn, Just to clarify, I'm not comparing `e.g.` here, I'm comparing `i.e.` with `viz`. Look at the sentence "he likes some fruits, viz, apples and oranges". The viz part is restating/clarifying the previous part "some fruits". In this case, wouldn't `i.e.` be more appropriate?

Comment: @Pacerier - If you say "fruits, viz apples and oranges" then you're listing specifically the only fruits he likes.  It's a limited list of examples.  I.e. is simply not intended to be used for a list of examples - that's what e.g. and viz. are for.  You can use it and be understood, but based on my understanding it would not be the most appropriate.

Comment: @Lynn, Are you saying that ""*He likes some fruits, i.e., apples and oranges.*"" is ungrammatical?: because it seems to be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Pacerier No, I'm saying that it may not be the correct or best choice depending on what you mean to say.  People often try to use e.g. and i.e. interchangeably to list examples but they technically mean different things.

Comment: “Viz.” is much closer in meaning to “i.e.” thanks to “e.g.”, thus I don’t particularly like this answer.

Answer (score 22):

You need to use e.g. in your example because the list is not complete

- [e.g. exempli gratia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.g.#exempli_gratia) - for example
- [i.e. id est](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28I%29#id_est) - that is
- [viz. videlicet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.) - that is
- sc. scilicet - namely (see [viz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.))

> In contradistinction to i.e. and e.g., viz. is used to indicate a detailed description of something stated before, and when it precedes a list of group members, it implies (near) completeness.

---

> A similar expression is scilicet, abbreviated as sc., which is Latin for "it is permitted to know". Sc. provides a parenthetic clarification, removes an ambiguity, or supplies a word omitted in preceding text,  while viz. is usually used to elaborate or detail text which precedes it. ... Scilicet can be read as "namely", "to wit", or "that is to say", or pronounced /ˈsɪlɨsɛt/ or /ˈskiːlɨkɛt/.

Comment: @mplungjan, So how does scilicet fit in? Is it identical to viz.?